# Get Commerce 2's Stripe subscription planData as object

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, stripe

How do I access a subscription plan's planData? Maybe as an object? I'm using Commerce 2 with the Stripe gateway.

For example:

```
{% set plans = craft.commerce.getPlans().getAllPlans() %}
{% for plan in plans %}
    {{ dump(plan.planData) }}
{% endfor %}
```

`planData` looks like JSON stored as a string. How do I access its data (`amount`, `trial_period_days` etc.) on the front end?

Does this need to be handled by a custom plugin? Seems like something that should be available out of the box. Hopefully I just over looked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subscription's `planData` is currently only stored as JSON. You can use that JSON in your template but you'll need to decode it first. Marion Newlevant’s [Twig Perversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion/) plugin adds a `json_decode` filter among other helpful capabilities to Twig.

With that plugin installed, set `planData` to a variable with the `json_decode` filter applied to it then you can access attributes of `planData` as you normally would in Twig.

```
{% set plans = craft.commerce.getPlans().getAllPlans() %}
{% for plan in plans %}
    {% set planData = plan.planData|json_decode %}
    {{ planData.plan.amount }}
    {# Stripe stores the amount as cents, so formatting for dollars or euros might look like this #}
    {{ (planData.plan.amount / 100)|currency }}
    {# Trial period  #}
    {{ planData.plan.trial_period_days }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like `|json_decode` is a native Twig filter. Looks like this plugin adds it though (not sure if it supports Craft 3). https://github.com/diit/Json-Decode-Twig I was hoping there was native support.

Comment: @SimonKuran — You are correct. I thought it was native in Craft 3, but I have Marion Newlevant’s [Twig Perversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion/) plugin installed which adds a `json_decode` filter and other helpful capabilities to Twig. Updated my answer with this info.

Comment: I believe that `json_decode` filter is now native (at least as of Craft 3.1.30)